# Attachment uploaded using VSTS REST API is not available for other users

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops

I used the VSTS REST API to upload an attachment to a work item using PATCH request and it went in fine. Now if I use another user in the same team project to access the attachment from the workitem, it says Unauthorized Read Access.

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402330: Unauthorized Read access to the attachment under the areas ","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemUnauthorizedAttachmentException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"WorkItemUnauthorizedAttachmentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3200}
```

Note: The other users I am using are created in the Azure AD on the default domain - ie - user.account@xyz.onmicrosoft.com

---

**Here are the Repro Steps:**

*Prerequsites*

1. Add a few users to VSTS - (I created  5 users using the default domain (xxxx.onmicrosoft.com) in my AzurePortal  - so the user id is like  test.user01@xxxxoutlook.onmicrosoft.com)
2. Add these users into a Collection level user group  in collection level security area
3. Add these users to the "Team" in project level security  area using the gropup created in step 2.

*Repro Steps:*

1. Using [C# Client Libraries here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/AttachmentsSample.cs#L23) upload an attachment to VSTS; To upload we need to use some form of authentication; the project uses VssCredentials which uses CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. I have tried this as well as Personal Access Token that can be created for any user in vsts user security area.

   2. After a successful upload, the API returns the reference url. Get the url;
   3. Stick the url in browser and try to get the file using the same account that was used to upload it; The file should showup/download successfully.
   4. Log off from vsts and login as one of the other users created in the prerequsites.
   5. Stick the attachment url in browser and try to get the file again;
   6. Instead of downloading the file, it throws Unauthorised read access.

      `{
      "$id": "1",
      "innerException": null,
      "message": "VS402330: Unauthorized Read access to the attachment under the areas ",
      "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemUnauthorizedAttachmentException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
      "typeKey": "WorkItemUnauthorizedAttachmentException",
      "errorCode": 0,
      "eventId": 3200
      }`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. (open work item> attachment> open attachment; Download attachment through REST API; Associate attachment to a work item). How does that user access attachment? What's the detail permission of that user? You can provide the detail steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: starain-MSFT , I have updated the post with all the necessary information. Hope that helps.

Comment: My end goal is to have my attachments in the description as a preview if it is a png file and a hyperlink if not; so that the reader can just get what they need all in 'Description'. When you do that using the UI it works - like pasting a screen-cut ; So I wanted to mimic the html produced as a result of such UI actions and send it in description via the API; but such preview/link cant be seen by other users! - Since all my attachments are badly named and I need to migrate 2500+ work items, without having inline links and images it'll be a pain to understand stories switching between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue before the upload user associate the attachment to a work item. There is a feedback that you can vote and follow: [VSTS REST API upload attachment file issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/100564/vsts-rest-api-upload-attachement-file-issue.html).

The workaround is that you can associate the attachment(s) to a work item, then others can access them.